# How can I create multiple gymnasium environments using `SB3` for manual use?

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I know that `SB3` provides various techniques to come up with vectorized environments. I want to limit myself to only using the vectorized environments and implement the RL algorithms from scratch. Would that be possible? My final objective is to learn how to play with RL hyperparameters on parallel environments in order to accelerate learning speeds. Currently, I am stuck on -

```
import os
import gymnasium as gym 
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv 
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: gym.make("CartPole-v1")]) 
obs = env.reset() 
done = False 
while not done: 
    action = env.action_space.sample() 
    next_obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action) 
    obs = next_obs
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\q_learning\dummy_envs.py", line 9, in <module>
    next_obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\anaconda3\envs\torch_2\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\vec_env\base_vec_env.py", line 197, in step
    return self.step_wait()
  File "C:\Users\thoma\anaconda3\envs\torch_2\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\vec_env\dummy_vec_env.py", line 59, in step_wait
    self.actions[env_idx]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```